# Flutter - Socket - SocketException Failed host lookup No address associated with hostname

Tags: flutter, sockets

My standard socket server works just fine. Internet connection is good. The code is good. The permissions are good. `flutter doctor` is also the best. `http.get()` even returned the perfect status code 200 response. All the issue is on client side the device not the server.

```
Socket socket = await Socket.connect('http://192.168.1.2', 5000);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> I/flutter (13238): SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'http://192.168.1.2' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

What was I missing?. Greatly appreciate your help and thank you.

Comment: You should be using: `await Socket.connect('192.168.1.2', 5000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No 'http://'.

```
Socket.connect('192.168.1.2', 5000)
```